# Anyone using Visual Assist? How does VA get the source code content?

Tags: visual-c++-6, visual-assist

I'm using Visual Assist with VC6, it seems to be a powerfull tool.
As a programmer, I'm curious about the implementation. I'm wondering how does VA get the source code content? it seems that VA knows every line of my code file, even when it's modified and not saved into file.

I've looked into addin dev for a while, VC6's addin interface doesn't provide such kind of interface to get current code content, especially when source file is modified and not saved.

I guess VA uses some tricks to do so, but what' it? Subclass?

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? Do you want an algorithmic explanation on how this can be achieved in genral or do you want to know specifics about the VC6 implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

surely VA is implemented as a visual studio add-on, which i guess would have access to some sort of visual studio API which i suppose would expose stuff like code editor content etc.

see this link for more info: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=59EC6EC3-4273-48A3-BA25-DC925A45584D&displaylang=en

hth

Answer (score 0):

I guess they use some kind of "hook" tech to monitor the change of source content. e.g. `SetWindowLong`/`SetWindowsHookEx`